# Struggling with XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the following XML documents, kinda simple:

```
<configuration>
   <group name="database">
        <server name="machine01" user="root" password="foob4r" sudo="true" hdd="300" loc="/opt" />
   </group>
   <group name="application">
        <server name="machine01" user="root" password="foob4r" sudo="true" hdd="50" loc="/export" />
        <server name="machine02" user="root" password="foob5r" sudo="true"/>
   </group>
   <group name="profiler">
        <server name="machine03" user="root" password="blue123"/>
        <server name="machine03" />
   </group>
</configuration>
```

`<configuration>` attribute is a **must**, and at **least one** `<group>` with **at least one** `<server>` is a **must**.
within the server, only the `name` attribute is a must.

I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="configuration">
    <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:element name="group">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:element name="server">
                    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                    <xsd:anyAttribute/>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

which doesn't do the trick, sadly.

Comment: What do you mean by `<configuration>` *attribute* is a must? `<configuration>` is an element and it doesn't have any attributes in your instance nor in your schema. I believe you meant *element*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can have *many* `<group>` child elements, then you must declare `maxOccurs="unbounded"`, because the *default*, when `maxOccurs` is not present, is `1`.

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="group"> ...
```

The same with `<server>`. In your schema it only declares `minOccurs="1"`. You need to add `maxOccurs` if you have more than just one. (You can also use *a fixed value*, such as `maxOccurs="2"` if only 2 servers are allowed.) The *attribute* `minOccurs="1"` guarantees that at least one `<group>` and at least one `<server>` must be present.

As for the attributes, you need to specify that they are not going to be validated. You can do that with the `processContents="lax"` or `processContents="skip"` when you use `xsd:anyAttribute`:

```
<xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
```

That's all. Your XSD with these corrections is shown below, and it should validate your instance:

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="configuration">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="group">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>

                            <xsd:element name="server" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:attribute use="required" name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>

                        </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>

            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I've added use="required"  to the <xsd:attribute name="name"> attributes and now it does the trick. thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that detail. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maxOcuurs is missing in ur XSD

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="configuration">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="group" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="server" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:anyAttribute/>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
 </xsd:schema>
```